# how to store character variable into two dimensional character variable

Tags: c++, string, char

I Want to store the value of user_uname and user_pwd to validuser[c][0] and validuser[c][1].Also string "normaluser" to validuser[c][2].
But it shows an error "cannot convert char * to char".This is my code:

```
char validuser[20][20];
int c;
char user_uname[20],user_pwd[20];
cout<<"\n Enter User Detail";
cout<<"\n enter Username:";
cin>>user_uname;
cout<<"\n Enter Password:";
cin>>user_pwd;
validuser[c][0] = user_uname;
validuser[c][1] = user_pwd;
validuser[c][2] = "normaluser";
c++;
```

Comment: you should just use a [`std::vector`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector) of [`std::string`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
char validuser[20][20];
....
validuser[c][0] = user_uname;
```

The validuser[][] is a char so you are not OK to assign. In your code, you can use:

```
strncpy( &(validuser[c][0]), user_uname, 20 );
```

But why dont you use the std::vector or std::array? In most of the case, std::string provide good enough feature for you.

Comment: If i put like this:    cout<<validuser[c][0]; It shows only first letter.but i want to store first whole string into validuser[c][0].If i put string validuser[20][20],shows error

Comment: How to assign string "normal user" to validuser[c][2].    void   Datamanagement::addUser()
    {

    char add_uname[20],add_pwd[20];
    cout<<"\n Enter User Detail";
    cout<<"\n enter Username:";
    cin>>add_uname;
    cout<<"\n Enter Password:";
    cin>>add_pwd;
    strncpy( &(validuser[c][0]), add_uname, 20 );
    strncpy( &(validuser[c][1]), add_pwd, 20);
    //validuser[c][2] = "normaluser";
    c++;

Comment: I think you mix up the direction of the array. you are actually want validuser[c] validuser[c+1] validuser[c+2]

Answer (score 1):

Your `validuser` is an array of arrays or chars. You can only store single `char` in each spot, or you can use it as an array of "strings" (char arrays). If you definitely want to use C style strings, you should have a third dimension to do what you're trying, such as `char validuser[20][3][20]`.

But since you are using C++, why not use `std::vector<std::string>` rather? And store usernames and passwords in a struct, not as consecutive strings. Using C++ strings and vectors will allow you to use any length of strings or any number of users without knowing the number beforehand or handling memory allocations yourself.

Answer (score 0):

You must use string on this. Char only accept a single character, here is the modified code. Hope this helps :)

The First Dimension you only need 3 array because of the user name, password, and type. for the 2nd Dimension you can add as many as you want, I made it 3 so that it would accept 3 users.

```
#include<iostream>
#include<string>
using namespace std;

void main()
{
    int pause;
    string validuser[3][3];
    int c = 0;

    do
    {
        string user_uname, user_pwd;
        cout << "\nEnter User Detail";
        cout << "\nenter Username:";
        cin >> user_uname;
        cout << "Enter Password:";
        cin >> user_pwd;
        cout << endl;

        validuser[c][0] = user_uname;
        validuser[c][1] = user_pwd;
        validuser[c][2] = "normal_user";
        c++;
    } while (c < 3);

    c = 0;

    do{
        cout << validuser[c][0] << " " << validuser[c][1] << " " << validuser[c][2] << endl;
        c++;
    } while (c < 3);

    cin >> pause;
}
```

Comment: It shows undefined symbol 'string'.Please rectify me

Comment: did you copy the #include<string> library. And copy the "using namespace std;" You might have forgotten it that is why you got the error. Try to copy the whole code that i posted its working fine :)

Comment: Will you do project for me.I will give you reward.quick Today i have to complete.

Comment: Post it here and I'll try to solve it. this site is an open source site for everyone to answer when they feel like doing so.